# Personalize Azure Bot - Extract Data for bot to use

Tags: azure, bots, personalization

I have a members-only website that takes personal information from each registered user. Each user account contains unique data related to the user that I want my bot to collect and then use to answer questions in the dialog.

A simple example is that I want the bot to grab the users name and greet them using it. There a few other pieces of data that I want the bot to extract from my site. How can the bot:

1. show up only when the user is logged into their account?
2. pull data from their account to personalize the conversation?

I have a PHP/Laravel website. I also use MySQL.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Unless you can [edit] your question and post some code as a [mcve] and ask specific questions about it, this question is way too broad and is likely to get closed.